# !_debugLocked is not true when making changes

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error when i make any changes to my app, i need to re run my app to get rid of this error. I tried to make some changes to my navigation but nothing changes. I also i'm searching for hours on the google to find something useful but i can't find anything to make it work.

**Note**: I'm beginner on Flutter development

**Main.dart:**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tasker/screens/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginDemo extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LoginDemoState createState() => _LoginDemoState();
}

class _LoginDemoState extends State<LoginDemo> {

  late ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String email = "";
  String password = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context);

    Future<String> getCurrentUserEmail() async {
      FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
      String userEmail = user.email.toString();
      return userEmail;
    }

    // Navigate user to HomeScreen if already singed in
    if (auth.currentUser() != null) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(userEmail: '',)));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 150,
                    /*
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),*/
                    child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage('https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1055/1055672.png'),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:15.0, right: 15.0, top:30, bottom: 0),
              //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.email = value;
                    });
                  },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Email',
                    hintText: 'Enter email'),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
              //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.password = value;
                  });
                },
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    hintText: 'Enter password'),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                // open reset password screen
              },
              child: Text(
                'Forgot Password?',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: TextButton (
                onPressed: () async {

                  progressDialog.show();

                  try {

                    AuthResult authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email.toString(),
                        password: password.toString()
                    );

                    FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

                    if (user == null) {
                      progressDialog.hide();
                      print("logged in");
                      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(userEmail: '',)));
                    }

                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e.toString());
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 130,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                // open reset password screen
              },
              child: Text(
                'New user? Sign up!',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {

    },),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple issues with the code, but the one which caused the `debugLocked` error was using future directly inside the build method, you either put the future in a `FutureBuilder` or run outside the build method.
Here is the code fixed:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:tasker/screens/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_progress_dialog/flutter_progress_dialog.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginDemoState createState() => _LoginDemoState();
}

class _LoginDemoState extends State<LoginDemo> {
  late ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String email = "";
  String password = "";

  Future<String>? getCurrentUserEmail() async {
    User user = await auth.currentUser!;
    String userEmail = user.email.toString();
    return userEmail;
  }

  // Navigate user to HomeScreen if already singed in
  @override
  void initState() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(
      child: Container(
        child: Text('Loading'),
      ),
    );
    
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void>? checkUserLoggedIn() async {
  if (auth.currentUser != null) {
    await  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
     Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomeScreen(
                    userEmail: '',
                  )));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Login"),
        ),
        body: ProgressDialog(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 150,
                        child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1055/1055672.png'),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 30, bottom: 0),
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.email = value;
                      });
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Email',
                        hintText: 'Enter email'),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.password = value;
                      });
                    },
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        hintText: 'Enter password'),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // open reset password screen
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Forgot Password?',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 250,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      showProgressDialog();

                      try {
                        UserCredential authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email.toString(),
                                password: password.toString());

                        User user = authResult.user!;

                        if (user == null) {
                          dismissProgressDialog();
                          print("logged in");
                          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                              context,
                              new MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => HomeScreen(
                                        userEmail: '',
                                      )));
                        }
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e.toString());
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 130,
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // open reset password screen
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'New user? Sign up!',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat);
  }
}
```